# File Revision Control

Tags: version-control, revision

How can I add a revision history in a file like shown [here](http://pastebin.com/m468e254c). Just to keep it simple and clean.

Comment: Why would you want that? Use an actual version control system instead of putting information in the file that's mostly useless.

Comment: I can understand you would want that in case you're distributing a couple of files to users and it makes sense to keep them informed the successive fixes or additions. However, a changelog generated by version control system used well (when you commit often) would contain much more entries than you want to appear in the file.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the feedback.

Well the reason I'm asking my question is because I think that using a VCS like Mercurial, SVN seems a little bit bloated to me when developing small, single-file scripts, e.g. Vim plug-ins, irssi scripts, backup scripts, whatever..), where the length of the main code doesn't exceed a few 100 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it was hand coded, but you could get something like that with a combination of a version control system and a bug tracking system, such as Jira and SVN.

Comment: Do you know if it's also possible with a VCS like Mercurial, bzr?

Comment: If you can get your bug tracking system to be Mercurial aware, I don't see why not. As to the specifics, I'm a SVN user, so I don't know.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your opinion anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the version control system that U use.  I don't know how to do it in SVN.  But it seem that you will have to digg deep into the version control messages that are input when a commit is done

Answer (score 0):

Many source control systems provide tags that can be embedded into a source file to automatically insert revision information (dates, users, history, comments, etc.) when embedded into the source code.  What those tags are depends on the system being used.

... assumes good use of version control